# Facebook app and magento multiple stores

Tags: magento, facebook-graph-api

I sat up facebook connect extension on my magento store. After filling api key, api secret in magento and config site url in facebook apps, the extension worked perfectly. However, if I switch to another store (with another domain), it won't work anymore. Is there a way to have magento connect to facebook without matching site url?

Here is the extension I got from: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/facebook-connect-magento-extension/

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this, and use extension it provided. http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/facebook-connect-magento-extension/
It worked for my multistore.

Comment: How could it be? It required store's domain and app's site url matching, when multistore have different domains.